# NextJS + Module Federation with ReactJS - style upload problem

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I have a project which using React18 and webpack5. It have module federation plugin. I want to use NextJS + module federation. Remote project is working correctly. Host project could not get styles from remote project. It looks terrible. Some styles fine some styles couldnot upload.

baseguicomponent-> host project
droninfocomponent-> remote project

I have style rendering problem.

Here my next.config.js for host project

```
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const packageJson = require('./package.json'); // Adjust the path accordingly
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// this enables you to use import() and the webpack parser
// loading remotes on demand, not ideal for SSR
const remotes = (isServer) => {
    const location = isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks';

    return {

        droninfocomponent: `droninfocomponent@http://localhost:3200/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`,

    };
};

module.exports = {
    /**
     *
     * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} config
     * @returns {import('webpack').Configuration}
     */
    experimental: {
        images: {
            unoptimized: true
        }},
        reactStrictMode: true,
        webpack5: true,
        webpack(config, {isServer}) {
            config.plugins.push(
                new NextFederationPlugin({
                    name: 'baseguicomponent',
                    filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
                    remotes: remotes(isServer),
                    shared: {
                        ...packageJson.dependencies,
                    },
                }),
                new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                    patterns: [
                        {
                            from: './public/images',
                            to: './public/images',
                        },
                        // You can add more patterns as needed
                    ],
                })
            );
            return config;
        },
    };
```

my host index.js file

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
const DronInfoApp = dynamic(() => import('droninfocomponent/DronInfoApp'), {ssr:false});

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <DronInfoApp />
        </Suspense>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And host package.json

```
{
  "name": "baseguicomponent",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3201",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3201",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
    "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "^7.0.7",
    "antd": "^5.4.6",
    "common-gui": "0.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "next": "13.4.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.81.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "none"
  }
}
```

my romete next.config.js

```
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    /**
     *
     * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} config
     * @returns {import('webpack').Configuration}
     */
    experimental: {
        images: {
            unoptimized: true
        }},
        webpack(config) {
            config.plugins.push(
                new NextFederationPlugin({
                    name: 'droninfocomponent',
                    filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
                    exposes: {
                        './DronInfoApp': './components/DronInfoApp.jsx',
                    },
                    shared: {
                        react: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '^18.2.0'},
                        next: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '13.4.13'},
                        webpack: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '5.81.0'},
                        eslint: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '8.34.0'},
                        axios: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '1.3.4'},
                        classnames: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '^2.3.1'},
                        antd: {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '5.4.6'},
                        "autoprefixer": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: "10.4.14"},
                        "postcss": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: "8.4.27"},
                        "tailwindcss": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: "3.3.3"},
                        "react-dom": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '^18.2.0'},
                        "eslint-config-next": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '13.1.6'},
                        "common-gui": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '0.0.1'},
                        "@stomp/stompjs": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '6.1.0'},
                        "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '7.0.7'},
                        "@ant-design/icons": {singleton: true, requiredVersion: '5.0.1'}
                       
                    }
                },
                    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                        patterns: [
                            {
                                from: './public/images',
                                to: './public/images',
                            },
                            // You can add more patterns as needed
                        ],
                    })
                )
            );
            return config;
        },
    }
```

remote index.js file

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import DronInfoApp from '../components/DronInfoApp'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <DronInfoApp />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

remote package.json

```
{
  "name": "droninfocomponent",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3200",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3200",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
    "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "7.0.7",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.0",
    "airspeeder-flight-indicators-react": "1.0.4",
    "antd": "^5.4.6",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "common-gui": "0.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "next": "13.4.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-modern-drawer": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.81.0"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "trailingComma": "none"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

However, I want to share _app.js file for remote project

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../components/index.css'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

I don't understand why styles are shifting inside the host project while the standalone remote module looks fine. I couldn't understand why it didn't compile styles properly because of, I couldn't find enough module federation examples related to Next Js,

Answer (score 0):

Use MiniCssExtractPlugin: To extract styles into separate CSS files, it's better to use MiniCssExtractPlugin instead of style-loader. This plugin allows you to convert styles into one or multiple separate CSS files.

In both remote next.config.js and host next.config.js:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // ...
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
            ],
        });

        config.plugins.push(
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].css',
            })
        );

        // ...
    },
};
```

Use css-loader with modules: To prevent class name collisions, enable the modules parameter of the css-loader by setting it to true. This will automatically convert class names to unique names.

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        });

        // ...
    },
};
```

Use @loadable/component: To dynamically load components and styles, consider using @loadable/component. This library provides more precise control over which styles and components are loaded in each module.

Install @loadable/component:

```
npm install @loadable/component
```

In your code:

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

const DronInfoApp = loadable(() => import('droninfocomponent/DronInfoApp'));

// ...

return (
    <div>
        <Head>
            {/* ... */}
        </Head>
        <main>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <DronInfoApp />
            </Suspense>
        </main>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but; I am using Nextjs framework. I should use "next/dynamic" for loadable. 
 I fixed bug another way. I added next-with-less to nextjs config and I moved css to host project.